# Count left attempts rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this MYSQL Table :

```
    id      |      action   
 A6bIMWP1rQ     changedusername
 A6bIMWP1rQ     changedusername
```

Now how i make this php function to count if more then 5 times changedusername exsit, it will return false?

i have tryed:

```
function checkIfOverFive($id,$mysqli) {
    global $func;  //The database connection

   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT action FROM userchange_attemps WHERE user_id = ?")) { 
       $stmt->bind_param('i', $id); 
      // Execute the prepared query.
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      // If there has been more than 5 failed logins
      if($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
         return true;
      }else{
         return false;
      }
  }
}
```

And how with php i determine how much left attemps upto 5 ?
Lets say now in my table theres 2 rows, and left 3 , how i return that value to the user ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever seen or heard about SQL's `COUNT()`?

Comment: no..its time for example if you can thanks allot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

```
function checkIfOverFive($id,$mysqli) {
    global $func;  //The database connection

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM userchange_attemps WHERE user_id = ? AND action = 'changedusername'")) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id); 
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
        if($row['count'] > 5) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks i learned new thing, just now how i check if its more then five ? and also how i add more action like changefname and changedlname ?

Comment: You.. fetch the result which is a number representing how many rows there are and you check if it's greater than 5? Are you even a developer? These are simple things, are you modifying someone's script?

Comment: if($stmt->num_rows > 8) {
         return true;
      }else{
      return false;
      } like this ? also how i know how much left ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` print?

Comment: Ok working,mistake with the query with name... anyway can u just help me how to determine how much attempts left ?

Comment: @Ravg `$attempts_left = 5 - $row['count'];` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
SELECT COUNT(action)
FROM userchange_attemps
WHERE action = 'changedusername' AND user_id= ?
```